# how do I traverse rows in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named members with 3 rows.  The following code attempts to display all the rows in the members table.  It displays the 1'st record 3 times instead of displaying each record once.

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "jce123", "profile");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($res);
    $array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    $keysarray = array_keys($array);
    $valuearray = array_values($array);
    for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        for($j = 0; $j < count($array); $j++) {
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr><td>".$keysarray[$j].": </td><td>".$valuearray[$j]."</td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            }
            echo "<br><br>";
        }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I've updated this per suggestions:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($res);
    $array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        foreach($array as $key => $value){
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr><td>".$key.": </td><td>".$value."</td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            }
        echo "<br><br>";
        }
```

Comment: instead of nested for loops, why not a use foreach to iterate once over your $array variable? Also, use of mysql & mysqli functions should be discouraged in favor of PDO

Comment: I used foreach($array as $key => $value) and it streamlined things quite a bit, but I still output the first record 3 times.  I would like to learn the OOP approach but need to finish this this morning.

Comment: @JasonFingar: MySQLi is (relatively) fine, since it fixes the gaping security and functional holes left by ext/mysql. I personally prefer PDO, but there's no real critical reason to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have `$array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);`, you will only receive one row from your database.  You need something like:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) 
{

// processing for each row

}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but that just gives me the first row twice.

Comment: You're still referencing $array in the loop, which is just the one row.  Iterate over $row instead:

`foreach($row as $key => $value){`

Comment: I took another look at this and changed my code to: while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  foreach($row as $key => $value){
   echo "<table>";
   echo "<tr><td>".$key.": </td><td>".$value."</td></tr>";
   echo "</table>";
   }
and now the only problem left is how to get the first record to display

Comment: You have the <table> tag inside your loop, so you're effectively creating a table for each row.  You should instead surround your loop with <table> and </table>.

Comment: yes it creates a new table for each record and double spaces between the tables in the outer loop which is fine.  With your help all is working now except the first record isn't being written only the second and third.

Comment: Remove `$array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);`.  You don't need that, it's just advancing the pointer one row.

Comment: u right me wrong all I had to do was put the table tags outside the loop.   Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

That's because, your $num = 3, count($array) = 3 and the outer for loop has no bearing on inner for loop.

Comment: I understand that but still don't know how to address the rows of the table.  I'm sure there must be some construct that represents a table as an array of records/rows

Answer (score 0):

Any basic tutorial will tell you this. Even the [PHP docs](http://php.net/mysql-fetch-assoc) provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use do something like this..

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) 
{

    // processing for each row
    e.g
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['name'];
    etc
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this... this peace of code is not tested but just to give you an idea...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($res);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            echo "<table>";
            echo '<tr><td> id = "'.$row['id'].'": 
                  </td><td> name = "'.$row['name'].'"</td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
    }
```